# Installed elastic search on server but cannot connect to it if from another machine

Tags: elasticsearch

**Context**

Have just started using `elastic search`, installed it on server, can `curl` and `telnet` to `port 9200` on `local machine(server)` but cannot connect to it if from another machine.

I disabled firewall on both the server and client as solutions I got from internet were suggesting and also tried suggestions found on the link below but couldn't get it working.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/accessing-port-9200-remotely/21840

**Question**

Can some one help me on how to get this working, thanks in advance

Answer (score 15):

Since you just installed Elasticsearch, I suppose you're using ES 2.0 or 2.1. You need to know that since the 2.0 release, Elasticsearch [binds to localhost by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_network_changes.html#_bind_to_localhost) (as a security measure to prevent your node from connecting to other nodes on the network without you knowing it).

So what you need to do is simply to edit your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file and change the `network.bind_host` setting like this:

```
network.bind_host: 0
```

Then, you need to restart your node and it will be accessible from a remote host.

Comment: @scott_lotus its works, also some one who ever needs this solution should remember to remove the  # from elasticsearch.yml (un comment the configuration that is being changed)  e.g "#  network.host: xxx.xx.xx.xxx"  to  "network.host: xxx.xx.xx.xxx"

Answer (score 8):

Let's recreate your scenario. I started freshly installed elasticsearch on my machine. Now I am able to perform curl on **port 9200**

```
[root@kali ~]# hostname -i
192.168.109.128

[root@kali ~]# curl http://localhost:9200

{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Kali Node",
  "cluster_name" : "kali",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.1",
    "build_hash" : "b88f43fc40b0bcd7f173a1f9ee2e97816de80b19",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-07-29T09:54:16Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

If you check the listening tcp ports on your server that java service has opened.

```
[root@kali ~]# netstat -ntlp | awk '/[j]ava/'
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      3422/java

tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9300          :::*                    LISTEN      3422/java
```

You can see elasticsearch is listening on **127.0.0.1** so it is obvious that you can't access port 9200 from the network. Let's verify it using wget from remote server.

```
$ wget.exe 192.168.109.128:9200

--2015-12-25 13:30:18--  http://192.168.109.128:9200/
Connecting to 192.168.109.128:9200... failed: Connection refused.
```

lets change the elasticsearch configuration to fix the issue using below command

```
[root@kali ~]# sed -i '/^network.bind_host:/s/network.bind_host: .*/network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0/' /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

or

just open elasticsearch configuration file and find "**network.bind_host**" and do following changes below

```
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
```

then restart your elasticsearch service

```
[root@kali ~]# service elasticsearch restart
Restarting elasticsearch (via systemctl):                  [  OK  ]

Now lets check the listening tcp port of java

[root@kali ~]# netstat -ntlp | awk '/[j]ava/'

tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN      3759/java

tcp6       0      0 :::9300                 :::*                    LISTEN      3759/java
```

Now you can it is listening on all interface.

Lets try the wget command from remote machine

```
$ wget.exe 192.168.109.128:9200

--2015-12-25 13:39:12--  http://192.168.109.128:9200/
Connecting to 192.168.109.128:9200... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 328 [application/json]
Saving to: ‘index.html.1’

index.html.1                   100%[====================================================>]     328  --.-KB/s   in 0.009s

2015-12-25 13:39:12 (37.1 KB/s) - ‘index.html.1’ saved [328/328]

Try curl command

$ curl.exe http://192.168.109.128:9200

{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Kali Node",
  "cluster_name" : "kali",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.1",
    "build_hash" : "b88f43fc40b0bcd7f173a1f9ee2e97816de80b19",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-07-29T09:54:16Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: Sometimes we need to restart the SSH connection after editing the config (e.g PuTTY)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation of the problem, +1

Answer (score 2):

For ElasticSearch version 5, you can edit the configuration file `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` and add the following lines

```
network.bind_host: 0
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.enabled: true
```

The cors are needed for plugins like Head or HQ on remote machine, because they make Ajax XMLHttpRequest requests

You can also define `network.host: 0` since it is a shortcut which sets the bind_host and the publish_host

Sources:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this worked for me:

1. In `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`:

   - Remove network.host (I believe this should only be used if you are accessing locally)
   - http.host 192.168.1.50 (IP of the server)
   - http.port 9200
2. In `/etc/kibana/kibana.yml`:

   - server.host "192.168.1.50"
   - elasticsearch.hosts ["http://192.168.1.50:9200"]
3. In your nginx file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite.com`

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name 192.168.1.50;

    auth_basic "Restricted Access";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.50:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

4. Then restart all services and WAIT for a few minutes - I wasn't patient enough the first few attempts and wondered why it kept failing:

```
systemctl restart elasticsearch
systemctl restart kibana
systemctl restart nginx
```

5. After waiting for a few minutes, check that the ports are now on the correct IPs.

```
netstat -nltp
```

It should now look something like:
192.168.1.50:5061
192.168.1.50:9200

6. Test by trying to telnet from the remote machine by doing

```
telnet 192.168.1.50 9200
```

7. Now you are all set to access remotely or set up auditbeat etc.